# What is this SMD component

Tags: pic, pcb, components

[image: PCB]
Just out of curiosity I am trying to find out. What type of component is the green flat one in the picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Polyfuse- a kind of self-resetting current limiting device.  There are a few different names for them. Here is a [datasheet](http://www.belfuse.com/pdfs/0ZCH.pdf).

[image]

As far as names go, here is [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse#Device_trade_names)'s take on it:

> These devices are sold by different companies under various trademarks, including PolySwitch (TE Connectivity), Semifuse (ATC Semitec), "Fuzetec" (Fuzetec Technology), Polyfuse (Littelfuse) and Multifuse (Bourns, Inc.).[4] PolySwitch is the earliest product of this type, having been invented at Raychem Corporation (now TE Connectivity) and introduced in the early 1980s. Due to common availability, electronics engineers and technicians often refer to this device as a "polyswitch", in the generic sense, regardless of actual brand.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a bunch. I suppose it is the same one that you can find on many arduino boards?

Comment: They are available with many (thousands) of different ratings and other specifications, so maybe not exactly the same.

Comment: I see, it is a PTC. I know what that is. ;) And it makes sense, of cause.

Comment: I've never liked PTC since they don't really have a Temperature Coefficient like the NTC Steinhart-Hart equation but most of the other names (like Polyfuse) are trade names, so I suppose it will have to do.